# Summation Series for fractions

Tags: summation

I have a summation series of the form: $n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 +\ldots  + 1$. Is there a formula for this series? Basically, the denominators are powers of 2.

Comment: why the last term is $1$, shouldn't it be $\frac{n}{2^q}$

Comment: Is each term the integer part of the last term divided by 2? What happens when $n = 6$? What is the sum then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is : it is the sum of the $\log n + 1$ first terms of a geometric series:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \frac{n}{2^i} = n\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} 2^{-i} = n\cdot\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{\log n + 1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right) = 2n - 1
$$

*Remark:* $\log$ is the binary logarithm, not the natural (i.e., $\ln$) one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Can you please explain how summation of `2^(-1)` becomes the fraction `(1-(1/2^(log n + 1))/1 - 1/2`? If you can direct me to a resource, I can read more about it.

Comment: It comes for the closed-form formula for a geometric progression (with ratio $\neq 1$); see for instance [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2^k$, the summation is $$1+2+2^2+...+2^k=\frac{1-2^{k+1}}{1-2}=2(2^k)-1=2n-1.$$